# Create a point inside a UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibezierpath

[image]

I need to make the path as in the image. I have figured out the circle part but stuck on how to place the point inside the circular part.

Comment: A dot could be a smaller circle that is filled ;). This tutorial might help you get the basics https://www.raywenderlich.com/162315/core-graphics-tutorial-part-1-getting-started

Comment: Correct, but how do I add it to the path?

Comment: That tutorial covers it, I am no expert been a while, have a look at the pic in the tutorial it has a similar scenario to draw the marker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a brand new UIView. In my example, I've named mine ProdView. Copy the following code:

```
    import UIKit

    @IBDesignable
    class ProdView: UIView {
        override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code

        let lineWidth: CGFloat = 2.0

        let canvas = CGRect(x: rect.origin.x + 1, y: rect.origin.y + 1, width: rect.width - 2, height: rect.height - 2)

        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: canvas)

        UIColor.black.setStroke()

        UIColor.black.setFill()

        circlePath.lineWidth = lineWidth

        circlePath.stroke()

        let circleDotWidth: CGFloat = 10

        let circleDot = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: -circleDotWidth / 2,
                                                y: -circleDotWidth / 2,
                                                width: circleDotWidth,
                                                height: circleDotWidth))

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

        context.translateBy(x: rect.width / 2, y: rect.height / 2)

        context.saveGState()

        let angle: CGFloat = (5 * CGFloat(Double.pi) / 3) - (CGFloat(Double.pi) / 2)

        context.rotate(by: angle)

        context.translateBy(x: 0, y: rect.height / 2 - (circleDotWidth / 2) + 4)

        circleDot.fill()

        context.restoreGState()

      }


    }
```

In the example above, I created the circle and gave it a stroke. I then created the circle dot taking into account it's width for its x and y CGRect values. I then get the current context and translate it to the centre of the view's rect. I then save the current context and rotate the context to 5pi/3 radians which I think is fairly close to where you want the dot. I subtract pi/2 because by default the context is skewed pi/2 radians from the start angle (or 0). I then translate the context to right where I want to fill the dot taking into account the circle dot's width and the line width of the circle and fill it to make it visible.

When I take out a UIView onto ViewController, setup the constraints and change it's class to ProdView and I get the following results (remember ProdView is IBDesignable so we can see the results in Storyboard):

[image: Circle Dot]